# whenever i use a \section with beamer i get an error

Tags: beamer, sectioning

so i get the following error

```
Overfull \vbox (47.46992pt too high) detected at line 25
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./TIPE.toc) [2])
Runaway argument?
{Introduction et contextualisation] \par \end {document} \par \par \par 
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

here's the code

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usecolortheme{seagull} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{Fira Sans}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\title{Comparaison de systèmes électoraux  }
\author{Essifi Yassine}
\institute{T.I.P.E}
\date{2021}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction et contextualisation]
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Un peu d'histoire }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! There was a bracket typo, now it should work fine:

```tex
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usecolortheme{seagull} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{Fira Sans}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\title{Comparaison de systèmes électoraux  }
\author{Essifi Yassine}
\institute{T.I.P.E}
\date{2021}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction et contextualisation}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Un peu d'histoire }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

As [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) made me notice, the package `titlesec` is incompatible with beamer.
In order to make it work, you should remove that packet!

Comment: i get another error `Overfull \vbox (47.46992pt too high) detected at line 25
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./TIPE.toc) [2]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.30 \section{Introduction et contextualisation}`

Comment: I just noticed something, let me check everything

Comment: @linko just to know are you trying to do something like this? https://ibb.co/ynWD70R

Comment: i just want to the section to show up in the tables of contents

Comment: @linko I made an edit

Comment: thaanks it worked